# Search on files in a folder

Tags: php

I have a search box on my site. If a student enters some text, the script must search for files with that type of name in a folder.

How to read folder and search for files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your OS and the magnitude of files in the folder, you could go about it a few different ways. The simplest way would be to use glob():

```
$safer = escapeshellarg( $_REQUEST['search'] );
$results = glob( "$dir/*$safer*" );
```

This should give you the same results as "ls *something*" in that directory.

If you have a more specific search pattern in mind and a modest magnitude of files in the directory, scandir() will give you an array you could use preg_match() on.

If you have a vast number of files, you might consider leveraging /usr/bin/locate, or /usr/bin/find. These kinds of shell executions from php do incur system load. If you have a large number of students, or a public facing search, then you will want to pursue a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [glob() entry](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) on the PHP Manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function, it can return a sorted list which you can then search in the same way you would search an array. You would then also be able to use an implementation of the [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to provide a "Did you mean?" style response from your application.

Answer (score 0):

MySql? you never connected to MySql or a db. plus the location of glob( "c:/windows/*$safer*" ) does not exist on a server.

if you want to search with glob, you need to use a couple ifs, elseifs and elses.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['s']) and $_GET['s'] != '') {
    $dir = 'dir/sub-dir';
    $ext = '.htm';
    $search = $_GET['s'];
    $results = glob("$dir/*$search*$ext");
    if(count($results) != 1) {
        foreach($results as $item) {
            echo "<li><a href='$item'>$item</a></li>\r\n";    
        }
    }
    if(count($results) == 1) {
        $item = $results[0];
        echo "<li color='blue'><a href='$item'>$item - only result</a></li>\r\n";
    }
    if(count($results) == 0) {
       echo "<li>no results to display</li>\r\n";   
    }
}
else {
    ?>
    <form action=''>
    <input name='s'>
    <input type='submit'>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```