# search files names in folder with PHP

Tags: php

i have a folder that i will save some files that their name will be the microtime that they will create.

there is any way to load **just** the group of the files names, that their name is bigger then the microtime that i will write?

(in `glob()` and in `readdir()` it load **all** the files names that in the dir, and just after that you can search whatever you want)

i will have in the folder a lot of files. so it will be inefficient to load all the files names first.

---

**example:**

*if in the dir i have this files:*

```
1413030375194

1413030375717

1413030377193  // for example, i want it to load from here

1413030377685

1413030378165

1413030378411
```

i want to load just the files that their name bigger then "1413030377000"

*so it will load to me **just** the files names:*

```
1413030377193

1413030377685

1413030378165

1413030378411
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(glob("*") as $file) {
  if($file >= $YOUR_MIN_FILE_NAME) {
    // do whatever you want...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$safer = escapeshellarg( $_REQUEST['search'] );
$results = glob( "$dir/*$safer*" );
```

Replace your file name with $_REQUEST['search']

Comment: i dont understand, what `escapeshellarg()` do?

Comment: thanks for trying help, but its not what i ask. i dont need to load the files names that have more characters, couse all the files have the same number of characters. i need to load the files name that their number (the files names is numbers) is bigger then the number that i write, without load all the others files names that i dont need. i will have in the folder a lot of files, so it will be inefficient to load all the files names first and just after that to search what i need.

Comment: okay no problem. i said Replace your file with $_REQUEST['search']. you can work with IF and do it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653864/search-on-files-in-a-folder